# Why didn't Thomas kill Darius immediately when he clearly hints he is behind his daughter's murder?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, edge-of-darkness

In *Edge of Darkness* (2010), Thomas and Darius talk about the mystery behind Emma's death.

> Darius: They're simply too complicated, too much hard work. There's a
>   lot going on out there in this world. And you just never can connect A
>   to B.
>
> Thomas: How do you know that?
>
> Darius: Because **I'm usually the guy that stops you connecting A to B.
>   It's part of what I do**.

He clearly indicates he is behind about her death and not allowing Thomas to know the truth about it.

Comment: Careful about spoilers in the question title, please.

Comment: I'm not sure that he clearly indicated that *he* was behind the death.